# Why Ansible didn't see attribute in variable?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, ansible

I have Ansible role "db" with simple task:

```
- name: Check repos
  apt_repository: repo="{{ item.repo }}" state={{ item.state }}
  with_items:
  - "{{ apt_repos }}"
```

In /defaults/mail.yml:

apt_repos:

```
   # Percona
 - { state: present, repo: 'deb http://repo.percona.com/apt wheezy main', keyserver: 'keyserver.ubuntu.com', key: '1C4CBDCDCD2EFD2A', needkey: True }
 - { state: present, repo: 'deb-src http://repo.percona.com/apt wheezy main', needkey: False }
```

When i try to run this ansible-playbook:

```
---
- hosts: test
  roles:
  - db
```

i see error:

```
fatal: [10.10.10.10] => One or more undefined variables: 'unicode object' has no attribute 'repo'

FATAL: all hosts have already failed -- aborting
```

But i have another role with same task and variable and it work perfectly. What's wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You want to be doing this:

```
with_items: apt_repos
```

apt_repos is a list.  By referencing it as `- "{{ apt_repos }}"` the extra `-` is turning it into a list of lists. You also don't need the quotes or braces in this case - those are pretty much just redundant in this type of situation.

Comment: In Ansible 2.1 and maybe earlier, this works but gives a deprecation warning due to use of the 'bare variable' `apt_repos`.  To avoid this, use `with_items: "{{ apt_repos }}"`.